# Average ELO of Tradewise Gibraltar Chess Festival 2016?

Tags: rating, tournament

I am wondering what the average ELO of the Tradewise Gibraltar Chess Festival 2016 is? And if it falls to any rating category that elite tournaments usually have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I didn't mess up my script the average Elo of the Gibraltar Masters 2016 is 2321.64.

That is category III and nowhere near a super tournament.

But of course if you only look at the top seeds the average is very comparable to super tournaments. (The top nine would be category XXI)

Basically after the first 4-5 rounds you have a full fledged super tournament going on at first 5 boards.